Safari font loading fails with 404 error - MyriadArabic-Regular.woff2 workaround needed
I'm experiencing issues with font loading in Safari, specifically with Myriad Arabic font and similar problem applies to other fonts in the same project. The browser developer tools show a 404 error when trying to load the font resource.
Environment:

Browser: Safari Version 18.1
Font format: .woff2, ttf, off

Current implementation:
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Myriad Arabic';
    src: url('../fonts/MyriadArabic-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/MyriadArabic-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/MyriadArabic-Regular.otf') format('otf');
    font-weight: 400;
    font-display: swap;
}

Error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()


404 means the browser can't find a file under the provided path. So double check your relative path. Keep in mind the URL must be relative to the final CSS file location. Pretty sure you can reproduce this error in Firefox or chromium as well.

What debugging have you tried? From the info given it just looks as though you are trying to load the fonts from the wrong folder. Where are they stored in relation to the code that is being run?

@AHaworth the font works fine on chrome, so I don't think it's a path location issue
this is their relative path: src/assets/fonts/PPEditorialNew-Regular.woff
here where they're rendered: src/assets/styles/01-settings/fonts.scss

@herrstrietzel  the font works fine on chrome, so I don't think it's a path location issue this is their relative path: src/assets/fonts/PPEditorialNew-Regular.woff here where they're rendered: src/assets/styles/01-settings/fonts.scss

Quite likely, you have this font also installed locally? Some browser can load local fonts others don't. If you're including the font.scss in you main CSS the path must be relative the the compiled CSS location - not the scss include. Quite likely, you need an extra traversal e.g ../../.

Are the tests of Chrome and Safari being done on the same device/OS?

@AHaworth yes it's on the same device

@herrstrietzel will try that out thanks!
